# Is it safe to use the -y and -Y flags to hdparm?

Tags: linux, hard-disk, power-management, hdparm

Is it dangerous to use the -y or -Y flag in hdparm during a write, or when the disk is still mounted, or will hdparm refuse to spin-down, or automatically sync and unmount?

Comment: Haven't tested recently, but I *think* it will spin down even while mounted. Give it a try, with a new/test partition if worried

Comment: hdparm man page has not listed those parameters as 'DANGEROUS', so I would assume that it is ok. Also, the same man pages mentions that Linux IDE drivers will handle the reset required to wake from sleep mode (-Y).

Answer (score 0):

(I am sorry for providing an answer which is not an answer, but a comment - for some reason I can't comment until I have 50 reputation.)

Just FYI: I recently issued (by mistake!) an hdparm -y command to my drive while mounted. I *don't* believe it was writing at the time, but definitely reading. It *did* make a "funny", mechanical noise, like a rattling, for a few seconds, but since then it has worked 100 % fine. It doesn't *seem* to be ruined. Yet.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is NO.
The hdparm manual pages specifies the "dangerous" flags/options for the command, eg the **-s** flag that allows the kernel to probe the disk for status while on standby on power on. This is reserved for RAID setups to avoid useless power consumption. A pedestrian user should stay away from it according to the aforementioned man pages.

Generally speaking avoid using APM (advanced power management) spind-down and/or stand by options on **NAS** flagged Hard disks. They are not designed for such implementation. Usually APM are not supported by such devices. The **-B** flag can help probing then setting teh APM level of a drive:

probing :  `hdparm -B     /dev/sdx`

setting :  `hdparm -B 127 /dev/sdx`

- 1-127 aggressive APM
- 1-128 gentle     APM
- 255   off        APM